# How I can solve: $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} a\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} a\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$ Hi, could someone explain to me how I can solve that limits, i thought that i could studying $L_2=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and do $a\cos(L_2)$, but I dont know if this way it is correct, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Tranform to polar coordinates with $x=\rho \cos \phi$ and $y=\rho \sin \phi$.  Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ doesn't exist. Consider, e.g. $y=cx$. From the continuity of $\cos$ the limit in question also does not exist.

Comment: I find it important to also note that $\arccos$ is continuous. Otherwise it could be that two wrongs made a right.

Comment: Oh! This $a\cos$ means $\arccos$, not $\cos$ multiplied by constant $a$?  But certainly, continuity is crucial.

Comment: I assumed it was $\arccos$, but it doesn't really matter. If you include this nuance in your answer, I will up vote it.